# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Currently i get an error, which says Fatal signal 11.

Unfortunately i do not get any other hints where to start to debug. Does anybody know where i should look at first?

I guess that it must be some kind of null-pointer exception and during bitmap-processing. Can i force to suspend the debugger on this exception?

```
04-24 14:48:31.007: A/libc(605): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1056 (AsyncTask #1)
04-24 14:48:31.107: I/DEBUG(310): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-24 14:48:31.107: I/DEBUG(310): Revision: '0'
04-24 14:48:31.107: I/DEBUG(310): pid: 605, tid: 1056, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.comp.app.myapp <<<
04-24 14:48:31.107: I/DEBUG(310): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     r0 00000000  r1 41492730  r2 447ebb78  r3 00000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     r4 447eb790  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 41492730
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     r8 80000000  r9 414cf348  sl 41492730  fp 447eb800
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     ip 0000000c  sp 75d2dac0  lr 00000000  pc 414cf2d4  cpsr 20070010
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d26 400bb9d3beb8c86b  d27 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310):     scr 60000010
04-24 14:48:31.197: I/DEBUG(310): backtrace:
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #00  pc 0003a2d4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #01  pc 0002ba40  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapBitmapScanWalk(HeapBitmap*, void (*)(Object*, void*, void*), void*)+100)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #02  pc 0003a5dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapScanMarkedObjects()+44)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #03  pc 0002bf24  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCollectGarbageInternal(GcSpec const*)+348)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #04  pc 0002ca0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMalloc(unsigned int, int)+228)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #05  pc 0006bfcf  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #06  pc 000246b4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAsmSisterStart+500)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #07  pc 00030c6c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #08  pc 0002e304  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #09  pc 00063435  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #10  pc 00063459  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #11  pc 00058137  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #12  pc 0000d258  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #13  pc 0000d3f0  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310): stack:
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2da80  44eed490  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2da84  00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2da88  75d2daa8  [stack:1056]
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2da8c  00000011  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2da90  77f1d895  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2da94  41492730  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2da98  00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2da9c  80000000  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2daa0  41572b48  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2daa4  414cf0a4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2daa8  447eb790  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2daac  41558e18  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dab0  00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dab4  41492730  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dab8  80000000  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dabc  414cf260  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #00  75d2dac0  447eb700  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dac4  000ca25c  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dac8  00032898  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dacc  00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dad0  414927fc  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dad4  414c0a44  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapBitmapScanWalk(HeapBitmap*, void (*)(Object*, void*, void*), void*)+104)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #01  75d2dad8  00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dadc  447eb700  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dae0  41492730  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dae4  41492718  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dae8  41492730  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2daec  4003f0c0  /system/lib/libcutils.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2daf0  41558e18  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2daf4  4003f028  /system/lib/libcutils.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2daf8  00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2dafc  0ce4e1ed  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2db00  00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2db04  414cf5e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapScanMarkedObjects()+48)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):     #02  75d2db08  446fd000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2db0c  4154fb5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2db10  41492718  
04-24 14:48:31.207: I/DEBUG(310):          75d2db14  414c0f28  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCollectGarbageInternal(GcSpec const*)+352)
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310): memory near r1:
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492710 73757300 00000063 41492778 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492720 447054a0 446fd880 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492730 414927fc 6d00caaa 62562d2c 62562000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492740 0aaaaaaa 446fd000 447eb800 6d00d000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492750 00180000 00400000 000000b0 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492760 00000003 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492770 00000000 000000c3 00000300 00800000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492780 20000000 0c000000 0321da30 ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492790 00080000 00800000 446fd008 08e65000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     414927a0 007ff170 007e0000 0001aa68 446fd000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     414927b0 4d562000 44efd000 41562008 0319b000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     414927c0 0314ece0 0392f000 0000cc46 41562000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     414927d0 446fd000 446fd000 00000002 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     414927e0 41562000 20000000 61d62000 00800000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     414927f0 00800000 41562000 44efc338 61562000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492800 00800000 00800000 41562000 44efc338  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310): memory near r2:
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebb58 4157b400 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebb68 00000001 00000000 00000000 0000004b  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebb78 41562e90 00000000 0000000c 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebb88 447ebb00 447ebbc0 447ebc38 447ebcb0  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebb98 447ebd28 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebba8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebbb8 00000000 00000033 447e1ea8 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebbc8 00000000 415630e0 415621e8 447eb8f8  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebbd8 00000000 415630e0 447eb928 00000082  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebbe8 00000000 0000004b 44781040 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebbf8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebc08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebc18 4157b400 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebc28 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000033  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebc38 447e1ea8 00000000 00000000 41562350  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447ebc48 415621e8 447eb968 00000000 41562350  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310): memory near r4:
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb770 00000000 0000001b 41562e90 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb780 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000023  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb790 415621e8 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb7a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000001b  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb7b0 41571a90 00000000 00000005 447ebb78  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb7c0 00000005 0000001b 41571a90 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb7d0 00000001 447eb7e0 00000001 0000004b  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb7e0 41562e90 00000000 0000000c 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb7f0 415621e8 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb800 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb810 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb820 00000000 00000023 41571e88 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb830 447eb7c8 00000000 00000000 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb840 00000000 0000002b 415663c8 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb850 00000005 00000000 447eb870 447eb8f8  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb860 447eb968 447eb9f8 447eba78 00000033  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310): memory near r7:
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492710 73757300 00000063 41492778 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492720 447054a0 446fd880 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492730 414927fc 6d00caaa 62562d2c 62562000  
04-24 14:48:31.217: I/DEBUG(310):     41492740 0aaaaaaa 446fd000 447eb800 6d00d000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492750 00180000 00400000 000000b0 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492760 00000003 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492770 00000000 000000c3 00000300 00800000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492780 20000000 0c000000 0321da30 ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492790 00080000 00800000 446fd008 08e65000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927a0 007ff170 007e0000 0001aa68 446fd000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927b0 4d562000 44efd000 41562008 0319b000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927c0 0314ece0 0392f000 0000cc46 41562000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927d0 446fd000 446fd000 00000002 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927e0 41562000 20000000 61d62000 00800000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927f0 00800000 41562000 44efc338 61562000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492800 00800000 00800000 41562000 44efc338  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310): memory near r8:
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     7fffffe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     7ffffff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     80000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     800000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     800000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     800000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     800000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310): memory near r9:
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf328 e5840008 e5130004 ebffff73 e5943008  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf338 e594100c e1530001 8afffff6 e8bd8010  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf348 e5821018 e1a01002 eaffff6b e5900000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf358 e3500000 012fff1e e1a01003 e3a02001  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf368 eaffff23 e5900000 e3500000 012fff1e  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf378 e1a01003 e3a02000 eaffff1d e92d4038  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf388 e1a05000 e59f3054 e59f2054 e08f3003  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf398 e7930002 e5904388 fa00eff6 e30acaab  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf3a8 e34acaaa e3a02000 e1a01100 e5940024  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf3b8 e083c19c e1a011a3 ebff9547 e594c024  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf3c8 e3a02000 e1a00005 e5842030 e584c020  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf3d8 fa00f05a e584002c e3a00001 e8bd8038  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf3e8 0008389c fffffe58 e59f302c e59f202c  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf3f8 e08f3003 e92d4010 e7930002 e5904388  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf408 e594002c fa00ef0b e59f1014 e08f0001  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf418 e2841018 e8bd4010 ea01840d 00083838  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310): memory near sl:
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492710 73757300 00000063 41492778 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492720 447054a0 446fd880 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492730 414927fc 6d00caaa 62562d2c 62562000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492740 0aaaaaaa 446fd000 447eb800 6d00d000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492750 00180000 00400000 000000b0 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492760 00000003 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492770 00000000 000000c3 00000300 00800000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492780 20000000 0c000000 0321da30 ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492790 00080000 00800000 446fd008 08e65000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927a0 007ff170 007e0000 0001aa68 446fd000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927b0 4d562000 44efd000 41562008 0319b000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927c0 0314ece0 0392f000 0000cc46 41562000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927d0 446fd000 446fd000 00000002 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927e0 41562000 20000000 61d62000 00800000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     414927f0 00800000 41562000 44efc338 61562000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     41492800 00800000 00800000 41562000 44efc338  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310): memory near fp:
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb7e0 41562e90 00000000 0000000c 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb7f0 415621e8 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb800 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb810 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb820 00000000 00000023 41571e88 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb830 447eb7c8 00000000 00000000 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb840 00000000 0000002b 415663c8 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb850 00000005 00000000 447eb870 447eb8f8  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb860 447eb968 447eb9f8 447eba78 00000033  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb870 41566248 00000000 00000001 415621e8  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb880 41562698 41562698 447eb8a0 00000001  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb890 ffffffff 00000568 00000000 00000023  
04-24 14:48:31.227: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb8a0 415630e0 00000000 447eb8c0 3a3ed56c  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb8b0 00000000 00000010 00000000 0000003b  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb8c0 41563950 00000000 00000010 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     447eb8d0 00650073 00690072 006c0061 00650056  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310): memory near sp:
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2daa0 41572b48 414cf0a4 447eb790 41558e18  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2dab0 00000000 41492730 80000000 414cf260  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2dac0 447eb700 000ca25c 00032898 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2dad0 414927fc 414c0a44 00000000 447eb700  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2dae0 41492730 41492718 41492730 4003f0c0  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2daf0 41558e18 4003f028 00000001 0ce4e1ed  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db00 00000000 414cf5e0 446fd000 4154fb5c  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db10 41492718 414c0f28 00000038 000000c1  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db20 00000000 00001472 00001472 446fd008  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db30 00000001 00001472 41558e18 0000000a  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db40 44849e28 4150a0b5 ffffffff 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db50 00000000 41558e18 40093394 00001472  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db60 00000001 00000000 40093394 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db70 44849e28 414c1a10 75d2dbd8 77f1d008  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db80 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     75d2db90 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310): code around pc:
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf2b4 e3520001 d8bd80f8 e594c058 e35c0000  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf2c4 d8bd80f8 e3a05000 e594e05c e1a01007  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf2d4 e79e0105 e2855001 ebffff5c e5940058  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf2e4 e1550000 bafffff7 e8bd80f8 e594003c  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf2f4 e1a01007 ebffff55 eaffffcb 00083b18  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf304 fffffe58 e5903008 e590200c e92d4010  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf314 e1530002 e1a04000 98bd8010 e2430004  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf324 e1a01004 e5840008 e5130004 ebffff73  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf334 e5943008 e594100c e1530001 8afffff6  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf344 e8bd8010 e5821018 e1a01002 eaffff6b  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf354 e5900000 e3500000 012fff1e e1a01003  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf364 e3a02001 eaffff23 e5900000 e3500000  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf374 012fff1e e1a01003 e3a02000 eaffff1d  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf384 e92d4038 e1a05000 e59f3054 e59f2054  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf394 e08f3003 e7930002 e5904388 fa00eff6  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     414cf3a4 e30acaab e34acaaa e3a02000 e1a01100  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310): code around lr:
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
04-24 14:48:31.237: I/DEBUG(310):     000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
```

Comment: Are you using the NDK, either directly yourself or via a third-party library that you have linked with your app? Can you get this crash on the emulator?

Comment: I dont use the NDK in any way. I didn't try it on the emulator but the other developers get the same error.

Comment: I already checked the bugreport but i couldnt find any information which gets me ahead.

Comment: Try to post the AsyncTask that seems to be problematic

Comment: The key is whether or not this is tied to some specific manufacturer's firmware, or if it occurs across devices (or on the emulator, or on a Nexus device).

Comment: I'm getting a few instances per week of this on my Google Play developer console crash reports. FWIW, It's *mostly* on Sony hardware, but not exclusively (also occurred on Nexus 7, Note 3, and others). And I don't use the NDK in any way, though I do use a good bit of OpenGL.

Comment: Hint: Be careful using reflections in a thread ;)

Comment: Do you notice if it only happens on certain phones or OS's?  Ours was only on 8.1 or less and almost all were Samsung S8 or S7.